# Custom JSON encoder in Python 2.7 to insert plain JavaScript code

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-2.6

I'm trying to upgrade a portion of Python 2.6 code to Python 2.7. This code uses the `json` module to produce some JavaScript (not JSON-compliant), which is then inserted into the rest of a script.

The general idea is to be able to insert code or refer to variables that are defined elsewhere: it's not intended to be used as JSON data, but JavaScript code.

Here is the custom encoder that works in Python 2.6:

```python
import json

class RawJavaScriptText:
    def __init__(self, jstext):
        self._jstext = jstext
    def get_jstext(self):
        return self._jstext

class RawJsJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _iterencode_default(self, o, markers=None):
        if isinstance(o, RawJavaScriptText):
            yield self.default(o)
        else:
            json.JSONEncoder._iterencode_default(self, o, markers)

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, RawJavaScriptText):
            return o.get_jstext()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

testvar = {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 'abc',
   # RawJavaScriptText will be inserted as such, no serialisation.
   'c': RawJavaScriptText('function() { return "Hello World"; }'),
   'd': RawJavaScriptText('some_variable_name')
}

print json.dumps(testvar, cls=RawJsJSONEncoder)
```

Using Python 2.6, we get the required result:

```js
{ "a": 1, "c": function() { return "Hello World"; },
  "b": "abc", "d": some_variable_name }
```

Using Python 2.7, everything is turned into a string, thereby losing the validity of JavaScript code:

```js
{ "a": 1, "c": "function() { return \"Hello World\"; }",
  "b": "abc", "d": "some_variable_name" }
```

(As a side note, this is only every used with a pre-defined set of raw JavaScript value, so as to prevent potential injections or misuse.)

Of course, the reason for this is that `_iterencode_default` method of `JSONEncoder` doesn't exist in the Python 2.7 version of the `json` module. Admittedly, it wasn't meant to be overridden in the first place.

Is there another way to achieve this goal in Python 2.7? Using the foundations of a JSON library to be able to generate JavaScript code this way is rather convenient.

**EDIT:** Here is complete working solution, using replace as suggested by James Henstridge. I'm using random UUIDs for the replacement tokens, which should prevent any conflicts. This way, this is a direct replacement working with both Python 2.6 and 2.7.

```python
import json
import uuid

class RawJavaScriptText:
    def __init__(self, jstext):
        self._jstext = jstext
    def get_jstext(self):
        return self._jstext

class RawJsJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json.JSONEncoder.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._replacement_map = {}

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, RawJavaScriptText):
            key = uuid.uuid4().hex
            self._replacement_map[key] = o.get_jstext()
            return key
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

    def encode(self, o):
        result = json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
        for k, v in self._replacement_map.iteritems():
             result = result.replace('"%s"' % (k,), v)
        return result

testvar = {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 'abc',
   'c': RawJavaScriptText('function() { return "Hello World"; }'),
   'd': [ RawJavaScriptText('some_variable_name') ],
   'e': {
       'x': RawJavaScriptText('some_variable_name'),
       'y': 'y'
   }
}

print json.dumps(testvar, cls=RawJsJSONEncoder)
```

Result (2.6 and 2.7):

```
{"a": 1, "c": function() { return "Hello World"; },
 "b": "abc",
 "e": {"y": "y", "x": some_variable_name},
 "d": [some_variable_name]}
```

Comment: Just as an aside - is there any reason, you can't keep it JSON compatible, but instead of including the actual code, include it as a reference to the code, then have the Javascript the other end reference code?

Comment: @JonClements, it's not just about include actual code, but also variables (like the `some_variable_name` example). The JavaScript side needs to be able to make the difference between `"some_variable_name"` (the actual string value) and `some_variable_name` (which would then refer to the value in that variable).

Comment: Ah huh - that makes sense now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The undocumented private interface you were using appears to have gone away when the C extension used under the covers was expanded to cover more of the encoding process.

One alternative would be to insert place holder strings for your `RawJavaScriptText` values and post-process the output of `dumps` to convert those place holders to the form you require.

For example:

```
>>> data = {'foo': '@@x@@'}
>>> print json.dumps(data)
{"foo": "@@x@@"}
>>> print json.dumps(data).replace('"@@x@@"', 'some_variable_name')
{"foo": some_variable_name}
```

You'll want to be careful about this kind of technique if your JSON includes untrusted data: you don't want to be in a position where an outsider can add such place holders to the output unexpectedly.

Comment: Cheers, I've just added solution a solution using `replace` as you suggested. To prevent conflicts, I'm using random UUIDs within the custom encoder itself.