# JSON serializer class - why json.dumps() works while json.dump() does not?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization

I want to `json.dump()` a dictionary that has keys of `datetime.date` type, and to do so I made a serializer class to encode the `date` keys as strings. To my surprise it works with `json.dumps()`, but throws an error with `json.dump()`. At the end I was able to dump using a workaround, but I'd like to understand what happens here: why does the serializer class work with `json.dumps()` and does not work with `json.dump()`?

I tried writing a similar function to use with `default=` instead of `cls=`, tried rewriting this back and forth, tried to adapt some examples I found in the web, but I always ended up with the same error. I don't know what I'm missing here, even after reading the docs. Please enlighten me what do I need to change here to be able to serialize the dates and dump the dictionary.

Here is the MRE (Python 3.8.6):

```
import json
import datetime


class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):
    @staticmethod
    def convert_if_date(_date):
        if isinstance(_date, datetime.date):
            return _date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        return _date

    def date_insensitive_encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return {self.convert_if_date(k): v for k, v in obj.items()}
        return obj

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(JSONSerializer, self).encode(
            self.date_insensitive_encode(obj))


test_dict = {datetime.date(2022, 7, 10): 'OK'}

print(json.dumps(test_dict, cls=JSONSerializer))
# this prints: {"2022-07-11": "OK"}

with open('dump.json', 'w') as w:
    json.dump(test_dict, w, cls=JSONSerializer)
# but this throws a TypeError
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Progz/Python/AppKH/datacontrol/so_mre.py", line 28, in <module>
    json.dump(test_dict, w, cls=JSONSerializer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not date
```

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I'm not sure this is quite what OP is asking

Comment: @DeepSpace I know, and this is why it is in comments, not in the answer section below. I just put it here so other people can quickly determine which does what without needing to google search them.

Comment: The problem is the `encode()` method of the base `json.JSONEncoder` class is only utilized when the `dumps()` method is called, but not when `dump()` is. I encountered this issue once a while ago and figured-out something to make my custom  `JSONEncoder` work regardless of which one was used. I'll post an answer if what I did before can be applied to what you're doing…

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen: FWIW I think it's very improbable that your comment will help anyone — so suggest you delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [previous experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721412/355230), I thought the `encode()` method of the base `json.JSONEncoder` class was only used the when the `dumps()` method was called, and not when `dump()` was, however that's apparently **not** the case (so my previous solution didn't apply)…but the good news is I was able to do what I think you want done only in a different, simpler way that works with both methods — and it only requires overriding the `encode()` method to do so.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import json
import datetime


class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        # Convert dictionary keys that are datatime.dates into strings.
        if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
            for key in list(obj.keys()):
                if isinstance(key, datetime.date):
                    strkey = key.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    obj[strkey] = obj.pop(key)

        return super().encode(obj)


test_dict = {datetime.date(2022, 7, 10): 'OK'}

print(json.dumps(test_dict, cls=JSONSerializer))  # -> {"2022-07-11": "OK"}

with open('dump.json', 'w') as w:
    json.dump(test_dict, w, cls=JSONSerializer)  # # Works now, too.
```

Comment: Neat. Will have to have a closer look at that MutableMapping to understand what happens under the hood, but everything I need to go on is here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `MutableMapping ` is just a fancy (but generic) way of saying `dict`-like.

Comment: I just tried your code, adding `print("custom encode called")` right at the beginning of your `JSONSerializer.encode()` method. If it worked as you say, and your `encode()` was called in both cases (`dump()` and `dumps()`), "custom encode called" should be printed twice. However, for me, it is only printed once. So something seems to be off. I am on Python 3.11, by the way. So given your answer is already two years old, this might also be a version issue.