# Custom json encoder not being called

Tags: python, json

I tried to apply martineau solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931719/json-serializer-class-why-json-dumps-works-while-json-dump-does-not/78233402#78233402) to a slightly different case, but it seems that for some obscure (at least to me) reason, the custom encoder isn't called from the json.dump() method.

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import json
import numpy as np

class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        # Convert dictionary keys that are tuples into strings.
        if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
            for key in list(obj.keys()):
                if isinstance(key, tuple):
                    strkey = "%d:%d" % key
                    obj[strkey] = obj.pop(key)

        return super().encode(obj)

class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, states, alpha=0.15, random_factor=0.2):
        self.state_history = [((0, 0), 0)] # state, reward
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.random_factor = random_factor
        
        # start the rewards table
        self.G = {}
        self.init_reward(states)


    def init_reward(self, states):
        for i, row in enumerate(states):
            for j, col in enumerate(row):
                self.G[(j,i)] = np.random.uniform(high=1.0, low=0.1)
    
    def memorize(self):
        with open("memory.json", "w") as w:
            json.dump(self.G, w, cls=JSONSerializer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    robot = Agent(states=np.zeros((6, 6)), alpha=0.1, random_factor=0.25)
    print(robot.G)
    robot.memorize()
```

When testing the string encoding it seems to return what I'm expecting, but when the call to json.dump happens, the custom encoder doesn't seem to be called at all. Do you have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I added a 3rd solution that used @AbdulAzizBarkat's suggestion to override the `default()` method. It needs careful implementation though. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be considered an implementation detail of the `json` package, and also it might be a Python version thing. In any case, it becomes crucial with your implementation:

- The `dump()` function internally calls the `iterencode()` method on your encoder (see lines 169 and 176 [in the actual source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c8ac8a32fd6de1960526561c44bc5603fab0f3e/Lib/json/__init__.py#L169).
- Yet, the `dumps()` function internally calls `encode()` (see lines 231 and 238).

You can verify this by adjusting `encode()` and overriding `iterencode()` in your `JSONSerializer` like so:

```py
class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        print("encode called")
        ...  # Your previous code here
        return super().encode(obj)

    def iterencode(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("iterencode called")
        return super().iterencode(*args, **kwargs)
```

… and you will see that only "iterencode called" will be printed with your test code, but not "encode called".

The other Stack Overflow question that you linked in your question seems to have the same issue by the way, at least when using a rather recent version of Python (I am currently on 3.11 for writing this) – see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931719/json-serializer-class-why-json-dumps-works-while-json-dump-does-not/72932299#comment137929561_72932299) to the corresponding answer.

I have two solutions:

1. *Either* use `dumps()` in your `Agent.memorize()` method, e.g. like so:

   ```py
   def memorize(self):
       with open("memory.json", "w") as w:
           w.write(json.dumps(self.G, cls=JSONSerializer))
   ```
2. *Or* move your own implementation from `encode()` to `iterencode()`, e.g. like so:

   ```py
   class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):

       def iterencode(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
           if isinstance(obj, MutableMapping):
               for key in list(obj.keys()):
                   if isinstance(key, tuple):
                       strkey = "%d:%d" % key
                       obj[strkey] = obj.pop(key)
           yield from super().iterencode(obj, *args, **kwargs)
   ```

   This 2nd solution seems to have the benefit that it works with both `dump()` and `dumps()` (see note below).

A note for completion: The `dumps()` function later seems to result in a call of `iterencode()`, as well (I did not track the source code so far as to see where exactly that happens, but from the printouts that I added it definitely happens). This has the following effects: (1) In the 1st proposed solution, as `encode()` is called first and we can make all adjustments for making our data JSON-serializable there, at this later point, calling `iterencode()` will not result in an error, any more. (2) In the 2nd proposed solution, as we reimplemented `iterencode()`, our data will be made JSON-serializable at this point.

**Update**: There are actually two more solutions. First, thanks to the comment of @AbdulAzizBarkat: we can override the [`default()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) method. However, we have to make sure that we hand over an object type for serialization that is not handled by the regular encoder, or otherwise we will never reach the `default()` method with it. In the given code, we can for example pass the `Agent` instance itself to `dump()` or `dumps()`, rather than its dictionary field `G`. So we have to make two adjustments:

1. Adjust `memorize()` to pass `self`, rather than `self.G`, e.g. like so:

   ```py
   def memorize(self):
        with open("memory.json", "w") as w:
            json.dump(self, w, cls=JSONSerializer)
   ```
2. Adjust `JSONSerializer.default()` to handle the `Agent` instance, e.g. like so (we won't need `encode()` and `iterencode()`, any more):

   ```py
   class JSONSerializer(json.JSONEncoder):
       def default(self, obj):
           if isinstance(obj, Agent):
               new_obj = {}
               for key in obj.G.keys():
                   new_key = ("%d:%d" % key) if isinstance(key, tuple) else key
                   new_obj[new_key] = obj.G[key]
               return new_obj  # Return the adjusted dictionary
           return super().default(obj)
   ```

Second, arguably the most simple solution is not using a custom `JSONEncoder` at all, but providing `json.dump()` with a JSON-serializable object directly. We can do this, for example, by moving the preprocessing of keys to `Agent.memorize()`:

```py
def memorize(self):
    obj = {}
    for key in self.G.keys():
        new_key = ("%d:%d" % key) if isinstance(key, tuple) else key
        obj[new_key] = self.G[key]
    with open("memory.json", "w") as w:
        json.dump(obj, w)
```

Final side note: In the first two solutions, the keys of the original dictionary are altered, following the code in your question. You probably don't want to have this though, as actually your instance should not change just because you dump a copy of it. So you might rather want to create a new dictionary with the altered keys and original values. I took care of this in the 3rd and 4th solution.

Comment: The simplest solution is to actually override the [`default` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It actually isn't. Overriding `default()` only works for objects that the encoder cannot handle by default. However, OP asks for a custom handling of dictionaries, which *are* handled by default. Try overriding `default()` in OP's `JSONSerializer`, e.g. with `def default(self, o): print("default called")`, and remove the other overrides. You will see that your custom `default()` will never be called.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have to correct myself. It *is* possible to use a custom `default()` method, but not with a dictionary, as written in my previous comment. However, we can use the `Agent` instance itself to be handed over to `dump()`, for example, as this is a Type that will reach the `default()` method. Thanks for pointing it out and sorry for disagreeing with you in my previous comment – it took me a while to figure out what you really meant!