# How can I serialize a Python list as a single line in JSON?

Tags: python, json

It appears to be that by default Python `json` module serializes a Python list using new lines between each element, like so:

```
"data": [
    -6.150000000000006,
    -0.5,
    0.539999999999992,
    0.5800000000000125,
    -4.6299999999999955,
    12.0,
    2.829999999999984,
    -1.4199999999999875,
    1.759999999999991,
    -1.25,
```

I would like to serialize the contents of this list on a single line, if possible. How can I do that?

I am using `json.dumps(data, indent=4)` to perform the serialization step.

Please note that this list structure is part of a larger dictionary structure, and I would like to retain the indentation for the serialization of that dictionary.

The intended purpose is that the dictionary should be human legible, whereas the contents of the list can be on a single line, and it is still relatively easy to read. The data in the list is also less important for human legibility.

Comment: It doesn't do it by default. `indent=4` tells it to spread over multiple lines with 4-character indentation.

Comment: If you want indentation for dictionaries, but not for lists, I don't think there's a way to do that with the built-in `json` module.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame... Yes I am serializing this as part of a dict structure

Comment: you could inherit from the default writer, special-case list dumping, and then pass it as the `cls` arg to `json.dumps()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement custom indentation when pretty-printing with the JSON module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249415/how-to-implement-custom-indentation-when-pretty-printing-with-the-json-module)

Comment: Just don't use the `indent` parameter. Or, is your question actually *how can I pretty print JSON but keep lists on one line?* in which case the proposed duplicate is the way to solve it.

Comment: @Nick yes that's exactly right - I have made an edit to make this clearer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible solution:

Serialize the list to a string first, then serialize the remaining contents of the dictionary.

There is a disadvantage to this:

- The code is more complex, serialization and deserialization must be done in two steps
- The list is now stored as a string literal rather than a list

... in other words it looks like this ...

```
my_list: "[]"
```

... instead of this ...

```
my_list: []
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The intended purpose is that the dictionary should be human legible ..."*

That's the problem; *JSON* is a *data-set*.

It looks like the most common solution is a *find-and-replace* *pattern*.

```py
import json, re
x = { 'y': [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
j = json.dumps(x, indent=4)
print(re.sub(r'(\d),\s+', r'\1, ', j))
```

Output

```json
{
    "y": [
        1, 2, 3
    ]
}
```

Comment: well *no*, OP wants the dictionary to remain indented, but the list of numbers *under that key* to be in a single line.