# Custom Json (de)serialisation?

Tags: python, json

I'm porting some code from .Net to python.

At one point, we need to translate arbitrarily complex json from one format to another.

Eg:

```
{"Query": 
    {
        "Boolean": {
            "Operator": "And",
            "Parameters": [
                {"Equal": {"Name": "Bob"}},
                {"Boolean": ...}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To...

```
{"Query": 
    {
        "Left": {"Name":"Bob"},
        "Right": {...},
        "Operator": "And"
    }
}
```

We were using Json.Net's excellent `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter` to hook into the serialisation / deserialisation process. We have 2 `JsonConverter`s which convert from the same objects to/from each of these formats.

```
Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
    Return GetType(QueryDefinition).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
End Function
```

This means we can pick out the bits we want to handle manually and allow the stock converter to do all the properties/values that we don't need to treat specially.

Is there any equivalent mechanism/framework in Python? or am I going to have to manually parse every property recursively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass the default JSONEncoder.

From: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

*"To use a custom JSONEncoder subclass (e.g. one that overrides the default() method to serialize additional types), specify it with the cls kwarg; otherwise JSONEncoder is used."*

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder

Example of usage: [Custom JSON encoder in Python 2.7 to insert plain JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188719/custom-json-encoder-in-python-2-7-to-insert-plain-javascript-code?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of that in use? ... That was fast thanks. I'll accept when the timeout's up