# Save dict of key and list of dict inside key to JSON where dictionary is stored by line

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a similar question to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896877/json-save-one-dict-per-line). However, my dictionary has a structure like the following

```
data_dict = {
  'refresh_count': 1,
  'fetch_date': '10-10-2019',
  'modified_date': '',
  'data': [
      {'date': '10-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello1'}, 
      {'date': '11-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello2'}
  ]
}
```

I would like to store it in JSON so that my data is still stored in one dictionary per line. Something like:

```
{
  'refresh_count': 1,
  'fetch_date': '10-10-2019',
  'modified_date': '',
  'data': [
      {'date': '10-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello1'}, 
      {'date': '11-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello2'}
  ]
}
```

I cannot achieve it using simply using `json.dumps` (or `dump`) or the previous solution.

```
json.dumps(data_dict, indent=2)

>> {
  "refresh_count": 1,
  "fetch_date": "10-10-2019",
  "modified_date": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "10-10-2019",
      "title": "Hello1"
    },
    {
      "date": "11-10-2019",
      "title": "Hello2"
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: Can you post the output of `json.dumps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a hack, but you can implement a custom JSON encoder that will do what you want (see [Custom JSON Encoder in Python With Precomputed Literal JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397279/custom-json-encoder-in-python-with-precomputed-literal-json)). For any object that you do not want to be indented, wrap it with the `NoIndent` class. The custom JSON encoder will look for this type in the `default()` method and return a unique string (`__N__`) and store unindented JSON in `self._literal`. Later, in the call to `encode()`, these unique strings are replaced with the unindented JSON.

Note that you need to choose a string format that cannot possibly appear in the encoded data to avoid replacing something unintentionally.

```
import json


class NoIndent:

    def __init__(self, o):
        self.o = o


class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyEncoder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._literal = []

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, NoIndent):
            i = len(self._literal)
            self._literal.append(json.dumps(o.o))
            return '__%d__' % i
        else:
            return super(MyEncoder, self).default(o)

    def encode(self, o):
        s = super(MyEncoder, self).encode(o)
        for i, literal in enumerate(self._literal):
            s = s.replace('"__%d__"' % i, literal)
        return s


data_dict = {
  'refresh_count': 1,
  'fetch_date': '10-10-2019',
  'modified_date': '',
  'data': [
      NoIndent({'date': '10-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello1'}),
      NoIndent({'date': '11-10-2019', 'title': 'Hello2'}),
  ]
}

s = json.dumps(data_dict, indent=2, cls=MyEncoder)
print(s)
```

Intermediate representation returned by `super(MyEncoder, self).encode(o)`:

```
{
  "fetch_date": "10-10-2019", 
  "refresh_count": 1, 
  "data": [
    "__0__", 
    "__1__"
  ], 
  "modified_date": ""
}
```

Final output:

```
{
  "fetch_date": "10-10-2019", 
  "refresh_count": 1, 
  "data": [
    {"date": "10-10-2019", "title": "Hello1"}, 
    {"date": "11-10-2019", "title": "Hello2"}
  ], 
  "modified_date": ""
}
```

Comment: this looks great! I'll try it and accept the solution soon!

Comment: can you try in Python 3 also? I actually cannot reproduce the output in Python 3. thanks!

Comment: You should tag your question python-3.x if that's what you're looking for. It works in 2.7.15 and 3.6.8 on my machine (after fixing `print`).

Comment: I tested it and it works great. Accepted the answer!